# What is the problem in this redux action and reducer?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I know that redux trigger react component to re-render once state of that component get changed but this doesn't happen in my situation.

**Action**

```
const addToCart = (product, cartProducts) => {
   let newCartProducts = [...cartProducts, product];

   newCartProducts = newCartProducts.reduce((acc, cur) => {
      let repeated = acc.find(p => p.id === cur.id);
      if(repeated)  repeated.quantity++;   
      else acc.push(cur);
      return acc;
    }, []);

    return {
      type: ADD_TO_CART,
      payload: newCartProducts
    }
}
```

**Reducer**:

```
export default (state = [], action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ADD_TO_CART:
            return action.payload;
        default:
            return state;
    }

}
```

The reducer returns a new state every time the action dispatched from the component but i need to close the cart and open it again to get the effect, redux does not update the product quantity simultaneously??

Comment: It's probably better to put the logic of not adding existing product to card in the reducer, something like `if(state.map(cardItem=>cardItem.id).includes(action.payload.newItem))`, if the redux dev tools say the item is added after the action is dispatched then your problem is probably in the container of the card items.

Comment: yes everything is well in the console? but the cart product quantity does not update until i close and re-open the cart...also i thought that action is a better place to put my logic and make the reducer just returns the data??

Comment: You can use the React dev tools to see what properties the component receives, I suspect something wrong in the container or in a reducer that you didn't post that mutates an object containing cart items instead of copying the object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are modifying the existing elements in the state.

Use

```js
newCartProducts = newCartProducts.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  let repeatedIndex = acc.findIndex(p => p.id === cur.id);
  const repeated = acc[repeatedIndex];
  if (repeated) {
    acc[repeatedIndex] = { 
      ...repeated,
      quantity: repeated.quantity + 1
    };
  } else acc.push(cur);
  return acc;
}, []);
```

You array is recreated each time, but the objects inside it are not. So when you modify their internals you need to notify that the specific object has changed.

Comment: There is a much simpler way to check if there are doubles and it should be done in the reducer not in the action. For example: `state.map(p => p.id).includes(newProduct.id)`. I don't see where OP mutates something in code posted redux dev tools is tricky as it will show diff on mutated changes.

Comment: @HMR The OP wants to a distinct set of products but with updated `quantity` property.

Comment: But i agree that there is a simpler method instead of doing it for all the cart all the time. Just check the cart and if not found add the new product, or if found update the one the needs updating.

Comment: I used that solution also but without reduce, it worked for me, but i still don't understand, i thought that changing the reference of the array make it a new state, should i change the reference of the internal modified object too???.. that is it??

Comment: so you both agree that logic in general should be in the reducer not action??

Comment: Yes that is the issue. Nested objects are a bit tricky as you have to destructure all the way to the property you want to modify :/

Comment: @CodeEagle Updated my answer, sorry I overlooked you were setting quantity. Assumed it was a complicated way to remove doubles.

Comment: Thank you guys, this discussion was very useful for me!!

Answer (score 2):

Refactor logic to the reducer and set the quantity here:

```
const addToCart = product => {
  return {
    type: ADD_TO_CART,
    payload: product,
  };
};
//I assume state is an array of products on your cart
export default (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_TO_CART:
      const { id } = action.payload;
      return state.map(p => p.id).includes(id)
        ? //product is already on card add quanity
          state.map(p =>
            p.id === id
              ? { ...p, quantity: p.quantity + 1 }
              : p
          )
        : state.concat({ ...action.payload, quantity: 1 }); // add product
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```